# How to fill a hole in a closed path with ai?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

See image for the hole between the beak and the eye that I want to fill.

[image: Picture of problem]

I have tried object -> path -> join and object -> path -> simplify with no success.

Comment: Note that your object is not a line, but a closed path; path > join works between 2 anchor points in an open path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to draw a new object that covers the hole. You can then combine the new shape with the existing shape with the Shape Builder Tool.

Comment: A litte Blob Brush Toll does this job too.